# Cant upload file Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503

Tags: php, ajax, upload

i have problem here that when i upload files in my upload script give me this error

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()`

i don't know why give me this error , sometimes i can upload successfully

iam using php , jquery , ajax

any help in this Error ?

[Image For Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFxsR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error.log file on your server which would give you (and us) more information - from just that screenshot we can only guess what's happening